# Calculate when two growth rates intersect

Tags: finance

If one publication has 15,000 subscribers and a growth rate of 15% (per year) and another publication has 20,000 subscribers and a growth rate of 4%, how long will it take the two to intersect? And how long do you calculate this?

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to StackExchange! Can you tell us what you've tried so far/what you've leaned in class about these types of problems?

Answer (score 0):

The growth rates would not intersect.

The numbers of subscribers would coincide.

Is 4% growth rate per year as 15% is?

Would you coumpound the growth rate?

On the second year would the amount be multiplied by $1.15^2 - 0.15$ of the original amount or simply increased by 15%?

Solve one of these accordingly

$15000*1.15^x = 20000*1.04^x$

$15000*(1 + 0.15x) = 20000(1 + 0.04x)$